# How to group rows in kableExtra with a grouping variable: `pack_rows()`?

Tags: r, grouping, kableextra

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tibble)
```

MWE dataset (group = grouping variable)

```
tib <- tibble(group = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
              var = 1:6)
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
kable(tib[, 2]) %>% 
  pack_rows(index = c("a" = 2, "b" = 1, "c" = 3))
```

But with 30 or more unique grouping identifiers this is tedious to do manually. So I have been experimenting with a programmatic approach

I tried using run length encoding but could not get it to work; for example, this code fails:

```
kable(tib[, 2]) %>% 
  pack_rows(rle(tib$group)[2], rle(tib$group)[1])
```

I'd be grateful for any pointers or suggestions to resolve this.

Comment: Maybe [collapse_rows](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#group_rows_via_multi-row_cell) is an alternative for you?

Comment: Thank you!! This solved it for me. Perfect.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use a simple `table`:

```
kable(tib[, 2]) %>% 
  pack_rows(index = table(tib$group))
```

[image]

If your index row is not alphabetical ordered you can do the following with `fct_inorder` from `forcats` (contained in `tidyverse`)

```
tib2 <- tibble(group = c("b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a"),
              var = 1:6)

kable(tib2[, 2]) %>% 
  pack_rows(index = table(fct_inorder(tib2$group)))
```

[image]

Comment: This method only works when the grouping variables are in alphabetical or numerical order, for example if `tib$group <- c("c", "c", "c", "b", "a", "a")` and `tib$var` is as before the "table" index method would not result in the correct grouping.

Comment: Then you can first use `fct_inorder` and then apply the table, see my edit.

Comment: @kath is there a way to do this with multiple columns?

Answer (score 2):

`group_rows()` is accepting a named vector. Here is one way:

```
kable(tib[, 2]) %>% 
  group_rows(index = setNames(rle(tib$group)[[1]], rle(tib$group)[[2]]))
```